# How do I use package.json to expose a .env file property?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, bash, environment-variables, create-react-app

I have a .env file that is supposed to define sensitive variables for me.  I have a package.json file that I want to expose these variables for but I'm getting an error that says the file can't be found.

Here is the .env file

```
REACT_APP_HTTPS=true
REACT_APP_SSL_CRT_FILE=C:\Users\techNerd\SSL\rootSSL.pem
REACT_APP_SSL_KEY_FILE=C:\Users\techNerd\SSL\rootSSL.key.pem
REACT_APP_PORT=3000
```

package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start":"set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE={process.env.REACT_APP_SSL_CRT_FILE}&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=process.env.REACT_APP_SSL_KEY_FILE&&react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=process.env.REACT_APP_SSL_CRT_FILE&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=process.env.REACT_APP_SSL_KEY_FILE&&react-scripts start
You specified SSL_CRT_FILE in your env, but the file "C:\Users\techn\WebstormProjects\AuthInMern2\client\process.env.REACT_APP_SSL_CRT_FILE" can't be found.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `[.env](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env) file?

Comment: `process` is a variable that is injected in Javacsript, so it is not defined in your package.json scripts. If you are using CRA, env variables that start with `REACT_APP_` will be accessible in your javascript files via `process.env`. Why do you want to rename the environmental variables?

Comment: Also you might want to  use [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env).

Comment: Actually, I don't have to rename them.

Comment: It's VERY important to know when using Create React App that you should **never use the `REACT_APP_` prefix for anything sensitive.** These values will be included in your client-side JavaScript bundle, and therefore will be exposed. See the Create React Docs for more information: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not using the variable inside of the React app, you can remove the `REACT_APP_` from the env var name.

In `.env`:

```
SSL_CRT_FILE=C:\Users\techNerd\SSL\rootSSL.pem
```

`package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start":"set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=$(grep SSL_CRT_FILE .env | cut -d '=' -f2)
react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Comment: I'm running Windows 10.  Anyway, I got it to work using "set cross-env " then entering in the actual file locations.  How much of a security risk is it when exposing paths to certificates?